# animate by 180 degrees - clicking twice results in random rotation values

Tags: android, user-interface, animation, rotation, icons

I use
 `image.animate().rotationBy(180).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()).start();` 
for a 180 rotation animation. 
[image]

However, if I press the icon twice quickly I end up with something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add code `imageView.setEnabled(false)` when rotation is starting and add `imageView.setEnabled(true)` when rotation ends. The code:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ImageView imageView  = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
    final ViewPropertyAnimator viewPropertyAnimator = imageView.animate();
    viewPropertyAnimator.setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationStart(animation);
            imageView.setEnabled(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            imageView.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            viewPropertyAnimator.rotationBy(180).setDuration(2000).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()).start();
        }
    });
}
```